# Excel VBA Code - How to adjust Page Setup for varying numbers of Rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Ok, So here is my goal.  I have a worksheet set up for an inventory count report.

Columns are:

SupplyName    |           Current Number in Inventory    |      Actual Count     |     Comments

The first two columns of this table are filled by the following excel formula:

=If (RepTemp!A2="","", RepTemp!A2)

You get the basic idea.

On the RepTemp Worksheet is a pivot table that will update based on the location selected for the inventory on the dashboard. This update is triggered by the selection of the location.

What I am trying to do is have a button that will open the print preview window, so that the report can be printed for the completion of the inventory.  My problem is some locations have up to 200 different products and some have 10.  I need the code that will ensure that regardless of the number of products at a given location, the printed report will only contain a maximum of 20 additional rows and not the entire 228 rows that currently exist.

Here is the code I developed:

```
Sub PrintIfNotEmpty()
Dim ra As Range, re As Range, i As Long, R As Range
ShInv.Rows("1:228").EntireRow.Hidden = False
Call Entry_Point
With ShInv
Set ra = .Range("A20:A228")
    For Each re In ra
        If IsEmpty(re.Value) Or re.Value = vbNullString Then
        re.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next re
End With
With ShInv.PageSetup
.Orientation = xlPortrait
End With
ShInv.PrintPreview

Call Exit_Point
End Sub
```

If I step through this code it works.  If I play it from the coding window it works.  If I attach it to a button it does not.  My question is this:

Is there a simpler way (via VBA) to achieve my goal?

Comment: Not sure why the button doesn't work. It seems like a more direct solution would be to directly print the pivot table after applying the appropriate filters. Can you explain why this was not the option chosen?

Comment: You can't format a pivot table to look pretty.

So I copy to another sheet that I can control fonts, colors, etc.

Turned out the macro was only attached to part (image) of the button, and therefore wouldn't connect to entire button.  Once I removed the macro from the image and put it on the group.  It worked fine.